# join results and perform arithmetic mean

Tags: mysql, sql, mean

Got two tables: "saldos_one" and "saldos_two", both tables got the following fields: CLIENTID, DATE, VALUE.

I have to get the TOTAL arithmetic mean from the arithmetic mean for each CLIENTID in some periods of time.

Lets take some examples:

```
> SELECT * FROM saldos_one;
+----------+------------+---------+
| CLIENTID | DATE       | VALUE   |
+----------+------------+---------+
| 1        | 2009-08-01 | 1000.00 |
| 1        | 2009-09-01 | 2000.00 |
| 1        | 2009-10-01 | 3000.00 |
| 2        | 2009-08-01 | 1000.00 |
| 2        | 2009-09-01 | 2000.00 |
| 2        | 2009-10-01 | 3000.00 |
| 3        | 2009-08-01 | 1000.00 |
| 3        | 2009-09-01 | 2000.00 |
| 3        | 2009-10-01 | 3000.00 |
| 4        | 2009-08-01 | 1000.00 |
| 4        | 2009-09-01 | 2000.00 |
| 4        | 2009-10-01 | 3000.00 |
+----------+------------+---------+

> SELECT * FROM saldos_two;
+----------+------------+---------+
| CLIENTID | DATE       | VALUE   |
+----------+------------+---------+
| 1        | 2009-08-01 | 10.00   |
| 1        | 2009-09-01 | 20.00   |
| 1        | 2009-10-01 | 30.00   |
| 2        | 2009-08-01 | 100.00  |
| 2        | 2009-09-01 | 200.00  |
| 2        | 2009-10-01 | 300.00  |
| 3        | 2009-08-01 | 1000.00 |
| 3        | 2009-09-01 | 2000.00 |
| 3        | 2009-10-01 | 3000.00 |
| 5        | 2009-08-01 | 1.00    |
| 5        | 2009-09-01 | 2.00    |
| 5        | 2009-10-01 | 3.00    |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

After QUERY arithmetic means for each table:

```
> SELECT CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2) 
FROM saldos_one 
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
GROUP BY CLIENTID;
+----------+---------+
| CLIENTID | VALUE   |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 2000.00 |
| 2        | 2000.00 |
| 3        | 2000.00 |
| 4        | 2000.00 |
+----------+---------+

> SELECT CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2) 
FROM saldos_two
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
GROUP BY CLIENTID;
+----------+---------+
| CLIENTID | VALUE   |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 20.00   |
| 2        | 200.00  |
| 3        | 2000.00 |
| 5        | 2.00    |
+----------+---------+
```

What I would like to get is the arithmetic means for each client from the arithmetic means of different tables, that will be:

```
+----------+---------+
| CLIENTID | VALUE   |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 1010.00 | = 2000.00 + 20.00 / 2
| 2        | 200.00  | = 200.00 + 200.00 / 2
| 3        | 2000.00 | = 2000.00 + 2000.00 / 2
| 4        | 1000.00 | = 2000.00 + 0 / 2
| 5        | 1.00    | = 2.00 + 0 / 2
+----------+---------+
```

SOLUTION: See @bvr's response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CLIENTID,SUM(VALUE)/2 VALUE FROM
(
    SELECT CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2) VALUE 
    FROM saldos_one 
    WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
    GROUP BY CLIENTID;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2) VALUE
    FROM saldos_two
    WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
) t
 GROUP BY CLIENTID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UNION` of the tables, and then perform your analysis on them.

E.g.

```
SELECT CLIENTID, AVG(VALUE) FROM (
    SELECT CLIENTID, VALUE FROM saldos_one WHERE 
       (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
  UNION
    SELECT CLIENTID, VALUE FROM saldos_two WHERE 
       (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
) t
GROUP BY CLIENTID
```

Comment: Your AVG won't do the right thing if a client ID is missing from one of the tables. The question says that the missing value should be treated as 0.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. Seems like only `bvr`'s answer takes this into account...

Answer (score 1):

```
select CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2)  from
(SELECT CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2)  as VALUE
FROM saldos_one 
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
GROUP BY CLIENTID
union all
 SELECT CLIENTID, TRUNCATE(SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE), 2) 
FROM saldos_two
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2009-08-01' AND '2009-10-01')
GROUP BY CLIENTID) as A group by A.CLIENTID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AVG function instead of SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(VALUE).

About final part of your question:

You can put in a temporary table the result of two queries and then apply to the temporary table the same query with AVG function, so you apply average between two values (2000 and 20).

And all rows of your table